# I need to figure out simple loops for a school project

Tags: c++, project

We are supposed to make a retail sales cashier but I just can't figure out the loops at all. We have only learned simple selection and repetition statements so far and I know that's all I need but I just can't seem to figure it out.

[Project Overview](https://cl1p.net/asfoasfjkasfa)

Starter Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double cashDrawer = 500.00;
    int productID = 0;
      int quantity = 0;
    double price = 0.0;
    double subtotal = 0.0;
    double salesTax = 0.0;
    double totalSale = 0.0;
    int anotherSale = 1;

    // Loop for repeat sales



    // Enter the first Product ID for the first sale (-1 to exit)



    // Main loop for each sale



    // Switch statement to determine the price, and calculate sales tax, if any, for the item.



    // Get next Product ID



    // Print properly formatted output for each sale



      // Another sale?



    // Display how much is in the cash drawer at the end


}
```

What I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double cashDrawer = 500.00;
    int productID = 0;
    int quantity = 0;
    double price = 0.0;
    double subTotal = 0.0; // for receipt purposes
    double salesTax = 0.0; // for receipt purposes
    double totalSale = 0.0; // for receipt purposes
    int anotherSale = 1;
    double taxRate = 0.075; // default tax rate

    // Loop for repeat sales
    while ()
    {
        
    
    


    // Enter the first Product ID for the first sale (-1 to exit)
    cout << "Enter the first Product ID: ";
    cin >> productID;


    // Main loop for each sale
    while (productID > 0) 
    {


        // Switch statement to determine the price, and calculate sales tax, if any, for the item.
        switch (productID) 
        {
        case 101:
            price = 65.00;
            taxRate = 0.075;
            break;
        case 102:
            price = 12.50;
            taxRate = 0;
            break;
        case 103:
            price = 24.50;
            taxRate = 0.00;
            break;
        case 104:
            price = 38.75;
            taxRate = 0.075;
            break;
        case 105:
            price = 17.80;
            taxRate = 0.075;
            break;
        case 106:
            price = 16.50;
            taxRate = 0;
            break;
        case 107:
            price = 42.85;
            taxRate = 0.075;
            break;
        case 108:
            price = 32.99;
            taxRate = 0.075;
            break;
        case 109:
            price = 28.75;
            taxRate = 0.075;
            break;
        case 110:
            price = 51.55;
            taxRate = 0;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "INVALID PRODUCT ID: Product ID not found." << endl;
        }

        cout << "Enter the quantity: ";
        cin >> quantity;

        subTotal += price * quantity;
        salesTax += price * quantity * taxRate;
        totalSale = subTotal + salesTax;
        
        // Get next Product ID
        cout << "Enter the next Product ID: ";
        cin >> productID;
    }

    // Print properly formatted output for each sale



    // Another sale?


    }
    // Display how much is in the cash drawer at the end


}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you guys in advance.

Comment: loops need a condition to tell them when to stop...

Comment: Which part of loops do you not understand?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Our community provides help for specific problems, also for homework. But not for the entire work, sorry. You should continue reading and learning and look for examples/tutorials in the web first.

Comment: You really need to start small and build up from there.  If you don't understand how to write a loop, then write a tiny program that does something with a loop, and figure it out.  Then add one thing to your program that brings you closer to your goal.  I might be to read a value inside the loop.  Get it working.  The next change might be to check if that input is a specific value and output a message.  Get that working.  Before long, you'll have a working program.  Experienced engineers do this too, by the way.  We just make much bigger changes because we can cope with the mental overhead.

Comment: Aside from your actual problem you are making the classic newbie mistake of trying to finish your program in one go. None of your code above has been tested at all. It can't have been because it doesn't compile. If you carry on writing more an more code without adequate testing you are going to end up with a mess of code with **multiple errors**. Such a mess is impossible to fix for a newbie because fixing one error doesn't make your code work (because there are still multiple errors to be fixed). So you have no idea if you are making progress. Such an approach is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Instead you should solve one problem at a time. Write you code slowly, adding to it piece by piece, and testing each piece as you go. Never write more code when the existing code hasn't been thoroughly tested and you are happy that it works. This means that you are going to have to set yourself a series of smaller goals instead of one big goal, but that's the way that professionals work.

Comment: TLDR; until you understand the language and how to read and fix compiler errors, you should avoid writing whole programs in one hit and then freaking out when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The basic aspect of a loop statement is to repeat the same set of instructions until a specified condition is met. You have successfully figured it out for the inner loop of your code where you are checking `if productID>0`. You need to do the same for the outer loop and impose a similar condition on `anotherSale` i.e. `while(anotherSale!=0)`. Every time the inner loop finish, just ask the user for the value of `anotherSale`; if the user enters 0, the loop should break.